# Селектор к элементу

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
Взял сайт на обслуживание, там написан следующий текст:

```
<div class="menu_dostavka_div">
<strong>Спайси унаги</strong>  (копченый угорь) – <span class="menu_dostavka_span">500 тг.</span>
<strong>Спайси эби</strong>  (креветка) – <span class="menu_dostavka_span">500 тг.</span>
<strong>Спайси магуро</strong>  (тунец) – <span class="menu_dostavka_span">550 тг.</span>
<strong>Спайси сяке</strong>  (лосось) – <span class="menu_dostavka_span">400 тг.</span>
<strong>Спайси тако</strong>  (осьминог)  -  <span class="menu_dostavka_span">500 тг.</span>
</div>
```

Как получить селектор к словам в скобке после тега `strong`?
Хочу сделать их меньшим шрифтом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нет возможности добавить к этим словам обёртку с классом, то можно сделать так:

1. Задать в  стилях меньший шрифт для `.menu_dostavka_div`
2. Задать шрифт побольше для `.menu_dostavka_div strong` и `.menu_dostavka_div span.menu_dostavka_span`

Вот как это будет выглядеть:

```
.menu_dostavka_div {
   font-size: 12px;
}

.menu_dostavka_div strong, 
.menu_dostavka_div span.menu_dostavka_span {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```